# error in converting python program to the exe form

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I am trying to convert program.py to program.exe but I am still receiving errors however I followed the right steps.

as an example of these errors:
**in32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (110, 'EndUpdateResourceW', 'The system cannot open the device or file specified.')**

Comment: Does your script use `win32`? Did you open the exe in the `dist` folder and which library did you use to convert to an exe

Comment: I sorry i can not understand the first part of the question (about win32). About the ```dist``` folder I found it empty . I used ```pyinstaller```

Comment: As a beginner I don't know what actually the ```win32-64``` is.

Comment: `win32api` its a library(module). The `dist` shouldn't be empty, that is where the exe should be, maybe share your code and `pyinstaller` code too